# replacing spark dataset column values randomly from a set

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Have a dataset imputedcsv where I want to randomly replace null values in Gender column with say Male or Female..

```
imputedcsv.groupBy("Gender").count.show()

+------+-----+
|Gender|count|
+------+-----+
|  null|   24|
|Female|  240|
|  Male|  242|
+------+-----+
```

One fill the null values by a single value, but how to fill the null value of the column randomly from a set of values say `{Male,Female}`

```
imputedcsv.na.fill("Male", Seq("Gender")).groupBy("Gender").count.show()

+------+-----+
|Gender|count|
+------+-----+
|Female|  240|
|  Male|  266|
+------+-----+
```

Instead of replacing the null values by just one value `Male`, I need to randomly fill it with either `Male` or `Female`.

Something like using `sample(c('Male','Female'))`

For single value we have [How to replace null values with a specific value in Dataframe using spark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671597/how-to-replace-null-values-with-a-specific-value-in-dataframe-using-spark-in-java)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider equal probabilities of Gender being either `Female` or `Male`, you can do something like this :

```
df.withColumn( "gender", 
    coalesce($"gender", 
                 when(round(rand).cast("int") === lit(0) , lit("Male") )
                 .otherwise(lit("Female"))
             )).show
```

`coalesce` makes it work only for `null` values.
`round(rand).cast("int")` will generate either `0` or `1` each time and then `Male` or `Female` will be decide by the `when - otherwise` construct.

Comment: It seems df.na.fill takes only one value...so for different runs we get either Male or Female randomly,,,,but once a value is obtained..that value is used to fill all the NAs..

Comment: val r = new scala.util.Random

val genderMap = Map(1 -> "Female", 0 -> "Male")                                  val newdf1=imputedcsv.na.fill( genderMap.getOrElse(Math.round(r.nextFloat) , "Female" ) )
newdf1.groupBy("Gender").count.show()                                                                                  Results: Run1: Male 242 Female 264 Run2: Male: 266 Female: 240

Comment: It works..Thank you.. any pointers ..explanation on how coalesce makes it work only for null values..

Comment: `coalesce` is a predefined function that takes an arbitrary number of columns. Supposed if a query is defined is `coalesce(a, "Hello")` then it will return `Hello` wherever a is `NULL` otherwise it will return the original value of column `a`. Please accept the answer so that the question is marked as resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted the answer. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with the use of `when & otherwise` along with `withColumn`, like this:

```
scala> df.groupBy("Gender").count.show

+------+-----+
|Gender|count|
+------+-----+
|  null|    2|
|female|    4|
|  male|    4|
+------+-----+

scala> df.withColumn("gender", when(($"gender".isNull), "male").otherwise($"gender")).groupBy("gender").count.show
+------+-----+
|gender|count|
+------+-----+
|female|    4|
|  male|    6|
+------+-----+
```

I missed `randomly`, you can achive it like below:

```
scala> val gender_set = Set("male","female")
gender_set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(male, female)

scala> import scala.util.Random
import scala.util.Random

scala>  val rnd=new Random
rnd: scala.util.Random = scala.util.Random@668b5a55

scala> df.withColumn("gender", when(($"gender".isNull), gender_set.toVector(rnd.nextInt(gender_set.size))).otherwise($"gender")).groupBy("gender").count.show
+------+-----+
|gender|count|
+------+-----+
|female|    4|
|  male|    6|
+------+-----+


scala> df.withColumn("gender", when(($"gender".isNull), gender_set.toVector(rnd.nextInt(gender_set.size))).otherwise($"gender")).groupBy("gender").count.show
+------+-----+
|gender|count|
+------+-----+
|female|    6|
|  male|    4|
+------+-----+
```

Thanks.

Comment: The above is fine if one wants to go with a single value.."male" in your snippet. I am exploring assigning a random value from "male" or "female".

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put @Learner's code in a UDF to work otherwise it would error.

```
df.groupBy($"Gender").count.show()
+------+-----+
|Gender|count|
+------+-----+
|  null|    3|
|Female|    3|
|  Male|    2|
+------+-----+
val gender_set = Set("Male","Female")

val randGenderUDF = udf(() => 
   gender_set.toVector(rnd.nextInt(gender_set.size))
)

df.withColumn("Gender", when($"Gender".isNull, randGenderUDF()).otherwise($"Gender")).groupBy($"Gender").count.show()
+------+-----+
|Gender|count|
+------+-----+
|Female|    5|
|  Male|    3|
+------+-----+
```