# Fill null values with empty string in Dataset<Row> using Apache-Spark in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

Please do not mark this question as duplicate. I have checked the below question and it gives solution for python or scala. And for java method is different.
[How to replace null values with a specific value in Dataframe using spark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671597/how-to-replace-null-values-with-a-specific-value-in-dataframe-using-spark-in-jav)

I have a Dataset `Dataset<Row> ds` which I created from reading a parquet file. So, all column values are string. Some of the values are null. I am using .na().fill("") for replacing null values with empty string

```
Dataset<Row>  ds1 = ds.na().fill("");
```

But it is not removing null values. I am unable to understand what can be the reason.

|-- stopPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- tradingCurrency: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your CSV (the rows for which "it is not working"), the output you get and the one you expect? It would really help us understand what's wrong.

Comment: Just to let you know, I tried your code and it works. Most likely, your values are not really null but I need more info to be certain.

Comment: Just updated my question. I am reading two files one is parquet and one is csv. both contain similar data. I am storing both to datasets ( Dataset<Row>). then i am using above code to replace null values with empty string. For dataset created from csv it is working and for dataset created from parquet it is not working

Comment: I tried Dataset<Row>  ds1 = ds.na().fill(0); and it is working. Does this fill method depends on datatype of column? If yes then i need to convert this column to String first. That will be messy. is there any clean method?

Comment: Can you print the result of `ds.printSchema()` in your question?

Comment: added. I figured it out. The column is double type. I used for(String c:df.columns()){
 df= df.withColumn(c,df.col(c).cast("string"));
 }

for converting all columns to String and then ds.na.fill("") worked fine

Comment: but is there any way i can change the schema of one dataset as per the schema of another dataset. Provided that both dataset contains similar columns and in same order

Comment: I had started to write an answer with an example. I posted it anyway, it could help others. Regarding your next question, you can apply a schema when you read a dataframe from a CSV file with `spark.read.schema(...).csv("xxx.csv")`. If the dataframe is already created however, you need to cast the corresponding columns. In your case, you could probably read the parquet file, extract the schema with `df.schema()` and use it when parsing the CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, your column has a numeric type. Also you cannot replace a null value by an illegal value in Spark. Therefore in your case you cannot use a string ("" in your case). Here is an example that illustrate this:

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark.range(10)
    .select(col("id"),
             when(col("id").mod(2).equalTo(lit(0)), null )
                 .otherwise(col("id").cast("string")).as("string_col"),
             when(col("id").mod(2).equalTo(lit(0)), null )
                 .otherwise(col("id")).as("int_col"));

df.na().fill("").show();
```

And here is the result

```
+---+----------+-------+
| id|string_col|int_col|
+---+----------+-------+
|  0|          |   null|
|  1|         1|      1|
|  2|          |   null|
|  3|         3|      3|
|  4|          |   null|
|  5|         5|      5|
|  6|          |   null|
|  7|         7|      7|
|  8|          |   null|
|  9|         9|      9|
+---+----------+-------+
```

It works for the string, but not for the integer. Note that I used the `cast` function to turn an int into a string and make the code work. It could be a nice workaround in your situation.