# Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$9: (string) => double) on using String Indexer for multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to apply string indexer on multiple columns. Here is my code

```
val stringIndexers = Categorical_Model.map { colName =>new StringIndexer().setInputCol(colName).setOutputCol(colName + "_indexed")}

var dfStringIndexed = stringIndexers(0).fit(df3).transform(df3) // 'fit's a model then 'transform's data
for(x<-1 to stringIndexers.length-1)
{dfStringIndexed = stringIndexers(x).fit(dfStringIndexed).transform(dfStringIndexed)
}
dfStringIndexed = dfStringIndexed.drop(Categorical_Model: _*)
```

The Schema shows up with all columns having nullable as false

The stringIndexers array shows up like this

```
stringIndexers: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer] = Array(strIdx_c53c3bdf464c, strIdx_61e685c520f7, strIdx_d6e59b2fc69d, ......)


dfStringIndexed.show(10)
```

This throws the following error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$9: (string) =&gt; double)
```

Why is it that print schema is showing up but no data is available .

Update: If I loop the string Indexers manually like so instead of the loop. This code works. Which is wierd.

```
var dfStringIndexed = stringIndexers(0).fit(df3).transform(df3) // 'fit's a model then 'transform's data
dfStringIndexed = stringIndexers(1).fit(dfStringIndexed).transform(dfStringIndexed)
dfStringIndexed = stringIndexers(2).fit(dfStringIndexed).transform(dfStringIndexed)
dfStringIndexed = stringIndexers(3).fit(dfStringIndexed).transform(dfStringIndexed)
dfStringIndexed = stringIndexers(4).fit(dfStringIndexed).transform(dfStringIndexed)
```

Adding Stacktrace on request

```
Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1823)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1772)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3273)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3253)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
  ... 63 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$9: (string) => double)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
  ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: StringIndexer encountered NULL value. To handle or skip NULLS, try setting StringIndexer.handleInvalid.
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$9.apply(StringIndexer.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$9.apply(StringIndexer.scala:246)
  ... 19 more
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your question?

Comment: Added the stack trace to the question

Comment: The error is that in some column that you are tring the StringIndexer has null values. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671597/how-to-replace-null-values-with-a-specific-value-in-dataframe-using-spark-in-java

Comment: It have checked that already . On print Schema i get Nullable = false and no nulls .Also when i am manuallly looping it is working

Comment: Have you try another approach like using fold and building a new dataframe each iteration..?

Answer (score 6):

I have also been getting a similar issue, even on a tiny subset of 50 rows, none of which have nulls in the column I am string indexing. But it didn't work even when I ran it manually.

I can avoid the error by including .setHandleInvalid("keep"), and I've checked the outputs and it's not doing anything strange like setting everything to be 0 or the same value or anything. I'm still unhappy about that being the resolution as it seems quite unsafe. Would be very interested to know if you found a more reasonable answer and resolution!

```
dfStringIndexed = stringIndexers(1).setHandleInvalid("keep").fit(dfStringIndexed).transform(dfStringIndexed)
```

I think it might also be fixed by changing the nullability of your column, even if it doesn't contain nulls in it, which I did as per here

[Can I change the nullability of a column in my Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072411/can-i-change-the-nullability-of-a-column-in-my-spark-dataframe?rq=1)