# Accesing fields of all the rows of a dataframe SPARK

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Alright so that seems easy but i couldnt find any solution or responses to it. I simply have a dataframe with a column full of nulls, and i just want to fill it with "s" or "n" randomly.

I tried this
`

```
df.foreach(f=>{
  
  if(random)
    f.get(4) = "s"
  else{f.get(4) = "n"}
})
```

`

But doesnt work, cause i think f is just a list, not the actual value
The pseudo would be something like that:

```
for(i=0;i<max_rows;i++)
  if(prob<.5)
   {df[i]["column_field"] == "s"}
  else
   {df[i]["column_field"] == "n"}
```

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow! In your pseudo code you are assigning only one value but in the beginning of your question you mentioned two values. Do you really need to have multiple values? If yes, they should be assign with equal probability or some custom probabilities?

Comment: Yes, i want to assign different values to each row, sorry, i have just edited that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all integer and long columns

```
df.na.fill(0)
  .show(false)
```

Replace with specific columns

```
df.na.fill(0,Array("population"))
  .show(false)
```

String type all columns

```
df.na.fill("")
  .show(false)
```

Specific columns

```
df.na.fill("unknown",Array("city"))
  .na.fill("",Array("type"))
  .show(false)
```

Comment: sorry but i cannot understand how are you accesing to each row of the dataframe

Comment: Please, see my answer 2.

Answer (score 0):

[DataFrame na fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671597/how-to-replace-null-values-with-a-specific-value-in-dataframe-using-spark-in-jav)

[Class DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html)

for your question new value to every row

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = Seq((0.5f, "v1"), (0.2f, "v2"), (1f, "v3"), (4f, "v4"))
  .toDF("prob", "column_field")
df1.show(false)
/*
+----+------------+
|prob|column_field|
+----+------------+
|0.5 |v1          |
|0.2 |v2          |
|1.0 |v3          |
|4.0 |v4          |
+----+------------+
*/
val resDF = df1.withColumn(
  "column_field",
  when(col("prob") <= 0.5f, "s")
    .otherwise("n")
)

resDF.show(false)
/*
+----+------------+
|prob|column_field|
+----+------------+
|0.5 |s           |
|0.2 |s           |
|1.0 |n           |
|4.0 |n           |
+----+------------+
*/
```